# I make two variables while using addition to result another value?

Tags: javascript, variables

So what I am asking is to look at the example given and maybe you'll understand what I mean by that.

If I have:

```
var x = "cheese";
var y = "bread";
var z = x + y; ( I want z = "sandwich" )
```

I just wanna know if that is possible and if it is, how to do it? I am a noob so please excuse my question if it is too stupid.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: That doesn't make sense at all. How would concatenating `cheese` with `bread` ever result in `sandwich`?

Comment: Sorry, that's why I am asking if it is possible!  Sorry for my stupid question.

Comment: `cheese + bread` doesn't that equal `cheese toastie`?

Comment: I guess it does! Just wanted to give a basic example :D

Comment: This isn't possible with strings, though you can do this with Objects

Comment: You would need to implement operator overloads and javascript doesn't support those.

Comment: I think what your after is just a lookup, but you would not use `+`,  with strings that just means concatenate them.  But you could create a simple lookup,  eg. `const lookups = {"cheese:bread": "sandwitch", "chocolate:milk": "hot chocolate"}` and then when you want the value -> `lookups[x + ":" + y]` would give you an answer.

Comment: Understood, thank you for your time to answer my stupid question! Really sorry and I don't wanna bother anyone here =D. I just wanna try to learn even if I will look like a retard asking questions...

Answer (score 1):

One (silly) option, if you're in the global scope, would be to pre-define `x` and `y` as un-writable properties on `window` with the `sand` and `wich` values, such that proceeding to do

```
var x = "cheese";
var y = "bread";
```

later in the code would not actually change `window.x` and `window.y`:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {
  value: 'sand',
  writable: false
});
Object.defineProperty(window, 'y', {
  value: 'wich',
  writable: false,
});



var x = "cheese";
var y = "bread";
var z = x + y;
console.log(z);
```

I don't think something like this would work anywhere other than on the global scope, otherwise `var x = <something>` *would* necessarily reassign `x` to the new value in that scope (or throw an error, for example, if `x` had been declared as a `const` or `let`)

Comment: it's a false assumption, because the assigned value does not matter. but anyway ... nice.

Comment: not what I had in my mind and I kinda got confused... rip :D but still thanks for your effort =)